# Accessing Objects from await - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await

One of my routes is returning an object coming from mongodb. When I receive the object I need to access its' keys but every key I am trying to access is coming back with undefined as a result.

Code:

```
const express = require('express')
const Review = require('../models/review')
const router = new express.Router()


router.get('/',async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const results = await Review.findById('some_id')
        const finalResult = JSON.parse(results) //still failing
        res.send(finalResult.rating)
    }catch (e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Response:

```
{
"_id": "",
"reviewerName": "Jane Doe",
"reviewDate": "2019-02-19T19:30:54.000Z",
"siteSource": "ReviewSite",
"rating": 5,
"reviewText": "Some text",
}
```

I was trying to access the rating by doing `console.log(results.rating) but is coming back as undefined.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the property? Client or server?

Comment: @Rashomon server

Comment: What does `console.log(results)` print?

Comment: @Rashomon the object above. Also tried `typeof` just for a sanity check and it is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `JSON.stringify()` the object first and then `JSON.parse()` it to be able to access the keys inside.

```
const test = JSON.stringify(results)        
const test2 = JSON.parse(test)
console.log(test2.rating)
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is in JSON format.
You have to convert the json to javascript object using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: you're probably correct, but no in-browser code is provided so we can't be sure.  @Geo, how are you calling this route?

Comment: @Geo , are you printing the response in the server or browser console?

Comment: @zacurry I am calling my route through Postman and also calling console to see the response in the terminal

Comment: Could you print the values before and after JSON.parse. Also , I see that there is a comma after "reviewText": "Some text" , which is not valid json.

Comment: @zacurry I will try that. Also, i removed some values from the object above for security reasons and forgot the comma you are seeing

Comment: @zacurry when I try to console.log the finalResult after JSON.parse the code is actually crashing....

Comment: Could you share the data that you are trying to `json.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the result to JSON object using JSON.Parse() method.

```
router.get('/',async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const results = await Review.findById('some_id')
        const finalResult = JSON.parse(results);
        res.send(finalResult.rating)
    }catch (e){
        res.status(400).send()
    }  
})
```

Answer (score -2):

just change it to

```
router.get('/',async (req,res)=>{
     try{
              const results = await Review.findById('some_id')
              const keys = Object.keys(results)
              res.send(keys)
     }catch (e){
     res.status(400).send()
    }  
})
```